# Why is solution file not in XML format?

Tags: .net-core

Why is my dotnet core solution file not XML?

For example, it has this...

```
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
```

Looks like Visual Basic.

As per usual, what is going on?

Comment: That's the way they built it.  I'm sure if they didn't have to support years of backwards compatibility with the format they'd have something that's more extensible / easier to work with.

Comment: XML based MSBuild syntax was only introduced in VS2005, decades ago. As solution file syntax, which was even older, were not changed for historical reasons and remains today.